# how I can do dialog box with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to delete a record through a php form where displays a confirmation message, and when you choose accept, delete the record and send me a message of successful operation. but without refreshing the page

Comment: you can do it with Ajax but what it has to do with dialog box?

Comment: what have you done so far? shehary suggestion will do that

Comment: Share your code mate.

Comment: is much the code and I dont know as place, but it made my pages, this one where the form and the other where the id is sent for delete, and also made the confirmation dialog box only that could not make the dialog box of successful operation, because it shows me only text and not the dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this by using Ajax, here i give to you sample illustration how to achieve that. But by using table as an example(since we don't know the HTML structured of yours) yet easy to implement and know how it works. Still the concept are same.

Here **HTML** structure

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Operation</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td> <a href="#" data-id="1" class="btnDelete">delete</a>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Johny</td>
    <td> <a href="#" data-id="2" class="btnDelete">delete</a>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John WHo</td>
    <td> <a href="#" data-id="3" class="btnDelete">delete</a>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Notice i use `data-id` to store the unique id of data. In your case, put inside your form and get it value using any matched jQuery selector. And below is a JS code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnDelete', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var $this = $(this);

  alert('My data id is ' + id);
  // find any dialog box available out there
  // using confirm box to choose either cancel or ok
  // if Ok was clicked, execute this below code
  if ( confirm('Are you sure to delete this data???') ){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // method used
        data: {
            id: id // send into php process page
        },
        url: 'serverSideProcessToDelete.php', // php process page
        success: function (data) {
            // data should be have 1 or 2 values in it
            // on success operation
            // remove DOM element from page
            // DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
            if ( +data == 1) {
                // remove dom element
                // if you're using form, try to figure out 
                // top level parent for removing part
                $this.closest('tr').remove();
                alert('Success Delete Data');
            } else {
                alert('Failed Delete Data');
            }

        }
    });
  }
});
```

And here **PHP** (serverSideProcessToDelete.php) code :

```
<?php
// connection things
$con = ......
// retrieved the data send from ajax
$id = $_POST['id'];
// do delete operation
$del = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = '$id'");
if ( $del ) {
  // send back to Ajax success callback
  // success
  $flag = 1;
} else {
  // send back to Ajax success callback
  // error delete
  $flag = 2;
}
echo $flag;
?>
```

[**This**](http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/) plugin very cool for message notification.
Tweak those code into your requirement. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks Norlihazmey Ghazali, I'll try , I know several things I hope to be successful

Comment: Glad to hear that mate!